# create a mysql view with merged rows

Tags: mysql

Hi I have a table like :

```
id_rel | id_art | id_fam | id_cat | id_scat | id_marca | id_model | id_year

  1      cw001      10       11        21       null       null       null
  2      cw001     null     null      null      233        455        466  
  3      cw001     null     null      null      234        456        467 
  4      cw001     null     null      null      235        457        468
  5      cw001     null     null      null      236        458        469
```

for a particular search query i need to combine it  in a mysql view like this:

```
id_rel | id_art | id_fam | id_cat | id_scat | id_marca | id_model | id_year

  1      cw001      10       11         21       233        455        466 
  2      cw001      10       11         21       234        456        467 
  3      cw001      10       11         21       235        457        468
  4      cw001      10       11         21       236        458        469
```

id-art it's the product id_fam | id_cat | id_scat it's the first group of products families,id_marca | id_model | id_year it's the secondo group.
I need to write a search query for combine the products group and have all values on the  same row it seems the best way for me.

So can you help me to create  this view?
Basically i have to copy the id_fam | id_cat | id_scat for each row.

I hope to be clear,sorry for my english
Thanks

Comment: Should the first row be a duplicate of the second, if you want to combine the details from both groups?

Comment: @MarkBannister no it's a my mistake on copy and paste,sorry

Comment: Stefano, can you update your desired output accordingly please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only want to see combined rows, try:

```
select g2.id_rel, g1.id_art, g1.id_fam, g1.id_cat, g1.id_scat,
       g2.id_marca, g2.id_model, g2.id_year
from myTable g1
join myTable g2 on g1.id_art = g2.id_art and g2.id_fam is null
where g1.id_marca is null
```

Comment: the data are stored on same table, i dont need a join,sorry i explain it bad

Comment: @StefanoSchivari: You *do* need a join, because the id_fam, id_cat and id_scat values are only present on one record for each id_art, yet you want them to show on every corresponding second group of values for the same id_art - this requires joining the table to itself. (This also implies that this table should be two different tables - one for the first group of values that only occurs once per id_art, the other for the second group of values that can occur many times for each id_art.)

Comment: ok understood and it works,seems i have to check well.Thanks so much,i learn a new stuff.P.s i fix the output